# Prevent Shared Perferences from reseting

Tags: android, xamarin, sharedpreferences

Each time I build the app in Xamarin, the SP resets.
It's really annoying to insert the values again in each build.

How can I just prevent the Shared Perferences from reseting when deploying an application?

`sp = Activity.GetSharedPreferences("Added_PC_List",Android.Content.FileCreationMode.Private);`

Comment: There should be a flag in the Xamarin options(`Tools>Options>Xamarin>Android`) to prevent wiping data between deploys. That will add a `-k` flag to the `adb uninstall <package name>` command which prevents wiping the data. http://adbshell.com/commands/adb-uninstall This should work given shared preferences are stored in your apps `/data/data/PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs` directory.

Comment: @JonDouglas Thanks for your time but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe there is a problem with the way I use it? Edited question.

Comment: For the record, I ticked `Preserve application data cache on device between deploys`.

Comment: Within the output logs, are you able to search and see a `adb uninstall` command? Does it have the `-k` parameter?

Comment: @JonDouglas Might be a nooby question but where do I check the uninstall log? Can't find it in the output window.. Also, that solution seemed to work once, but for some reason it doesn't work any longer..

Comment: You can use `adb logcat` or look at the logs in the `Help` section of Visual Studio. There's a Xamarin log location there.